# Ajax Polling while another ajax is running

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have one form on my page. When you submit the form I send Ajax call to the server. Server side is C# asp.net

Then controller on server is doing something and saving current state into Session. The ajax call is taking about 3 mins.

So I want to set ajax polling script, which will send ajax request to server every 5 seconds and read current stat from Session and updating frontend.

The issue is that ajax polling call is waiting until first ajax is done.

So while first ajax is running and doing some things on server side and updating current state in Session, I want another polling script which will reading this state from session in meantime, but the issue is that it just waiting for first ajax to be done.

What can be issue here. I low knowledge about sessions and just cannot figure out what the issue is and how to get this working.

```
function installation () {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () { checkStatus() }, 5000);
    var data = {//some data};

    $.post("/WebDomain/Installation", data, function (result) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        console.log(result);
    });
};

function checkStatus()
{
    $.post("/WebDomain/GetInstallStatus", function (result) {
            console.log(result.Status);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you considered SignalR for this? Sounds like a good fit: http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Well it sounds great. I wish I could implement it using web sockets. It would be better solution. But in this case I just need it with polling ajax if it's possible.

Comment: Are you using SQL for something? because the ajax should be async and you should be able to have multiple calls to the server, the problem could be multiple open connections (if SQL it's used). I don't know if I undestood

Answer (score 0):

```
    function installation () {

        var data = {//some data};

        $.post("/WebDomain/Installation", data, function (result) {
           setTimeout(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 5000);
        });
    };

    function checkStatus()
    {
        $.post("/WebDomain/GetInstallStatus", function (result) {
               installation ();
        });
    }


   $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 5000);

    });
```

Hope it will help

```
Explanation: after 5sec of your dom is ready checkStatus() will call,
if success only  installation (); will call 
In installation (); success we are again calling checkStatus(). 
now you can check some condition for breaking this iterations
```